# Number of times the callback needs to be called before executed

Tags: javascript, callback

I got presented 4 interview questions and one of them is this:

> Write a function `after` that takes the number of times the callback needs to be called before being executed as the first parameter and the callback as the second parameter.
>
> ```
> function after(count, func) {
>   // Implement the 'after' function
> }
>
> var called = function() { console.log("hello") };
> var afterCalled = after(3, called);
>
> afterCalled(); // -> nothing is printed
> afterCalled(); // -> nothing is printed
> afterCalled(); // -> 'hello' is printed
> ```

The way I solved the problem is this:

```
function after(count, cBack) {
  localStorage.setItem("aCount", count);
  return function () {
    let currCount = localStorage.getItem("aCount");

    if (currCount == 1) {
      cBack();
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("aCount", --currCount);
    }
  };
}

let called = function () {
  console.log("hello");
};

let afterCalled = after(5, called);

afterCalled();
afterCalled();
afterCalled();
afterCalled();
afterCalled();
```

I mean, the code works as intended but I have a feeling that localStorage is not the way. Am I missing somethig? Is there something in callback functions that I can use or I 'should' use to solve this problem? If so, what should I look up?

Comment: Hi, I think that the question was asked in order to verify your knowledge of the concept of closures so you can check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures and learn how to solve correctly the question.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably expected you to use the closure formed by calling `after` (see comments):

```js
let after = (count, callback) => {
    return () => {
        // Has our count reached one?
        if (count <= 1) {
            // Yes, call the callback
            callback();
        } else {
            // No, decrement the count
            --count;
        }
    };
};

let called = function () {
  console.log('hello')
};

let afterCalled = after(5, called);

afterCalled();
afterCalled();
afterCalled();
afterCalled();
afterCalled();
```

The `count` parameter continues to exist as long as the function that `after` returns exists, because the function `after` returns is a *closure* over the context where it was created. So you can use that to remember the number of times called.